# Is it possible to get the value about to be returned from set_trace_func?

Tags: ruby, trace

I'd like to write some Ruby code like this to see the value returned by every method called (from, say, a script):

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if event == "return"
    puts "returning #{return_value} from #{classname}.#{id}"
  end
}
```

Is this possible? Can I get `return_value`, somehow, in the scope of the code above?

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 2.0 has a new [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/TracePoint.html) class that includes a `return_value` instance method. You can use it like this:

```
trace_point = TracePoint.new(:return) do |t| # event type specification is optional
  puts "returning #{t.return_value} from #{t.defined_class}.#{t.method_id}"
end

trace_point.enable
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested on 1.9.3, there is a cludgy way to do this:

You can use `eval(code, binding)` to evaluate a called function from within the `set_trace_func` handler and then `eval` a returned value that you've taken note of.

You have to recompose the caller code yourself.
Something like:

```
arg_arr = []
params = eval('method(__method__).parameters', binding)
params.each do |param|
  case param[0]
        when :req, :opt
          arg_arr << param[1]
        when :rest
          arg_arr << '*' + param[1]
        else
          puts "Need handler for type #{param[0]}"
      end
end

call_expr = "#{id} #{arg_arr.join(',')}"
puts "Call with <#{call_expr}>"
res = eval(call_expr, binding)
puts "sub-method #{id} returned #{res}"
eval("return #{res.inspect}", binding)
```

You can only do this for one level down, because `set_trace_func` has been turned off for teh duration of its handler. Plus the output of `arguments` appears undocumented. Also, it uses evil.